# Pushforward of pullback

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f \colon X \to Y$ be a (proper if you want) morphism between two noetherian schemes. Let $X_0$ and $Y_0$ be two closed subschemes of $X$ and $Y$, with closed immersion $i \colon X_0 \to X$ and $j \colon Y_0 \to Y$, and let us suppose that we are given a morphism $g \colon X_0 \to Y_0$ such that the obvious square diagram is *cartesian* (not only commutative).

Let $\mathcal F$ be a quasi-coherent sheaf on $X$. Is it true that
$$
g_\ast i^\ast \mathcal F = j^\ast f_\ast \mathcal F \;\; ?
$$

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

No, even if $f$ is proper and flat, and $\mathcal{F}$ locally free (say). Take for $Y_0$ a closed point $y$ of $Y$, so that $X_0$ is the fiber $X_y$. You are asking whether the natural map $(f_*\mathcal{F})_y\rightarrow H^0(X_y,\mathcal{F}_{|X_y})$ is an isomorphism. This is not true in general. For a nice discussion of that issue, see for instance Mumford's *Abelian varieties*, §5 ("Cohomology and base change").

Comment: However, if $X$ and $Y_0$ are Tor-independent over $Y$ then $Rg_*\circ Li^* = Lj^*\circ Rf_*$.